# JAX-WS and WS-Transaction

Tags: transactions, websphere, jax-ws, ibm-rad

Posts: 53 
 posted Today 1:48:38 PM  0
I am developing a jax-ws web service proof of concept in RAD 8.0.4 and running in WebSphere 7. Our app uses Spring and Hibernate, but we're not exactly experts in either. We need to enable global transactions with our web service so it can work with the transactions of client apps. I followed the insctructions I found on various websites, including IBMs, and I thought I configured everything and it doesn't work. Each transaction (client and service) work fine independently, but I forced an exception before commit in my client. This rolls back the client transaction, but not the service transaction. Furthermore, the logging on websphere (not the simply systemout one...the trace from the admin console) spits out some gobbledy-gook that implies to me that no transaction context was offered from the client.

I initially set the policies in both the services view of RAD and the admin console, but I've since read that if you set both, it doesn't work. But I have since tried just one and just the other and neither work. Here's what i did:

In my wsdl I added:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="ATPolicy">   
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>   
      <wsat11:ATAssertion/>   
      <wsat10:ATAssertion/>   
      <!-- omitted assertions -->   
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>   
</wsp:Policy>
```

and the wsp:PolicyReference line

```
<binding name="TxPortBinding" type="tns:TxDelegate">   
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>   
<operation name="insertDBTrans">   
 <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#ATPolicy" required="true"/>         
  <soap:operation soapAction=""/>   
  <input>   
    <soap:body use="literal"/>   
  </input>   
  <output>   
    <soap:body use="literal"/>   
  </output>   
</operation>   
</binding>
```

In the admin console version, after importing the WS-Transaction policy, I navigated to Services->Service Providers->TxService, and selected the checkbox of all three level, TxService, TxPort, and insertDBTrans. Chose Attach Policy Set->WSTransaction. Click the disabled link on the service, and chose 'exported WSDL'. Ok & Save.

Then to Services->Service Clients->TxService. Check client, Attach Client Policy Set->WSTransaction. Client and provier policy chosen.

But that didn't work. So I remove them, and instead go into the services view of RAD. Right clicked on the service, manage policy sets. Put WSTransaction on the first page with Provider Sample as binding attached. It's set all the way down to the operation name - insertDbTrans.

Under the client in the services view I set the client to user provider policy, second page, chose WSTransaction for the default entry and it set to "client and provider".

I actually tried more permutations than this. But none of them worked.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Or at least a narrowing down of the general problem? Am I close to right?

Comment: When you mention insertDbTrans it looks to me you're actually doing a DataBase call in your server code. Questions: What database are you using? Did you configured the DataSource to use a XA driver?

Comment: Db2 9.5.  Yes, I am using and XA data source configured through the admin console's data sources.  The XA provider then points at the driver.  It's pointed at db2jcc4.jar and the class is com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource.

Comment: Am I even on the right path here?  Am I close?  Is there some major piece I didn't talk about that I should have?

Comment: @MarcosMaia - We use Transactional annotations to manage our transactions via spring.  The transaction manager is defined thusly: <tx:jta-transaction-manager id="transactionManager">
  <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction" />
 </tx:jta-transaction-manager>

Comment: @Marcos Maia - No new info, just wondering if I did the @ wrong and that might be why I didn't get another followup.

Comment: Hi, actually I stopped following up because I do have a lack of knowledge on Spring so I didn't feel I could help further. It looks to me like you're in the correct path but than I don't really know how to fit spring on this.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take spring out of the context. Do a very simple WebServices with DB interaction and try to put it in a transaction context. First make this simple example work and than add the complexity of your business case and Spring to it. That's how I would do it. ;)